# Invalid prop `data` supplied to `MaterialTable`, expected one of type [function]

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, jhipster

I am working in a jhipster application, with data coming from postgress sql. The api is http://localhost:8080/api/agreements and I am trying to display the data in a react material table but I am getting this error "Invalid prop `data` supplied to `MaterialTable`, expected one of type [function]" on my console after writing my functions.

Let me walk you through my codes below:

Inside the React component

```
  const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/agreements';
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);


    useEffect(() => {
    getAgreementsData();
    }, []);

    const getAgreementsData = () => {
    fetch(apiUrl)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => setData(res));
```

};

Inside the JSX

```
      <MaterialTable
      title="Agreements"
      data={data}
      columns={columns}/>
```

The columns are displaying but the data is not.

And this warning is on the console " GET http://localhost:8080/api/agreements 401 (Unauthorized)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I later resolved the error by using axios get instead of fetch.

```
     useEffect(() => {
     getAgreementsData();
      }, []);

     const getAgreementsData = () => {
     axios.get(apiUrl).then(res => setData(res.data));
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

i also have thiss error , i cant parse my data into table. but i find where it is problem.

i parse my data like object ->
export const CLIENT_DATA ={

```
 name: "Frontend site",
 contactPersonName: "Lukasz Swarz",
 contactPersonEmail: "lukasz@gmail.com",
 contactPersonPhone: "065438677282",
 description: "This is project, for car sell!",
 statusClient: "Active"
```

};

but you must do this with array brackets :

export const CLIENT_DATA =[{

```
 name: "Frontend site",
 contactPersonName: "Lukasz Swarz",
 contactPersonEmail: "lukasz@gmail.com",
 contactPersonPhone: "065438677282",
 description: "This is project, for car sell!",
 statusClient: "Active"
```

}];
in my case, this being problem, basic error,but take me a lot of time